# SFML 2.1 Networking

Tags: c++, networking, sfml

I was trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSwutjvNjK4&list=PLHJE4y54mpC5j_x90UkuoMZOdmmL9-_rg&index=22) tutorial, and I got this far.

```
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    sf::IpAddress ip=sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress();
    sf::TcpSocket socket;
    char connectiontype,mode;
    char buffer[2000];
    size_t received;
    cout<<"s for server, c for client"<<endl;
    cin>>connectiontype;
    string text="connected to ";
    if(connectiontype=='s'){
        sf::TcpListener listener;
        listener.listen(3000);
        listener.accept(socket);
        text+="server";
        mode='s';
    }
    else if(connectiontype=='c'){
        socket.connect(ip,3000);
        text+="client";
        mode='r';
    }
    socket.send(text.c_str(),text.length()+1);
    socket.receive(buffer,sizeof(buffer),received);
    cout<<buffer<<endl;

    bool done=false;

    while(!done){
        if(mode=='s'){
            getline(cin,text);
            socket.send(text.c_str(),text.length()+1);
            mode='r';
        }
        else if(mode=='r'){
            socket.receive(buffer,sizeof(buffer),received);
            if(received>0){
                cout<<"received: "<<buffer<<endl;
                mode='s';
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it, and got these errors:
[image]

I also tried adding `sfml-network-2.dll` and `sfml-network-d-2.dll` into my project folder, but it didn't work.

I'm also pretty sure that I set everything up correctly.
This is my setup:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I covered my name up, if you don't mind. Thanks!

Update:

I have reinstalled SFML, and I updated my code and my errors.

Comment: In my SFML / C::B setup on Windows, I don't put the path to the libraries, but their names: E.g. only sfml-window and not the whole path. It seems as `ld` wouldn't find the libraries. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem!
I changed each library to just the name, not where it is.
Example: `Desktop/SFML-2.1/lib/libsfml-network-s-d.a`->`sfml-network`

Comment: This is basically what I ment in my comment ;) Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

If you are pretty sure you have set up everything correctly, are you sure you added the SFML path to the Compiler include paths AND the SFML DLL to the Linker paths?

As you use Code::Blocks, have you setup your project "online game" exactly as described here?

http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php

**Update:**

Have a look at this picture:
http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/images/start-cb-link-libs.png

Are you sure, you've got `sfml-network` in the library list there? This might be the problem.

Adding the dlls to the project folder won't help, as it is a compiler/linker error and not a runtime library error.

Comment: I had sfml-network in the library list. I tried including SFML/System.hpp, but it didn't help.

Comment: Could you post a picture showing your project configuration? (The same dialog as above + the search directories)?

Comment: OK, I will.(now I got 10 rep to post pics)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to `sfml-system` too.

As a side note, you can find the official example about sockets [here](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/tree/master/examples/sockets).

Comment: I am linked to sfml-system.